# batch file programming to get email notification with text file data as a body of e mail

Tags: email, batch-file

I want a batch file program to get email.

For example I have a text file main.txt with some data

I want this to my mail id.  Can you please help me in this programming.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? what problems you found? what is your exact question? if you just want a hint to get you started, begin with BLAT, available at sourceforge.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got an email server you can send the emails to, I'd first recommend Blat as mentioned by PA's comment.

If you're running Microsoft Outlook email client, you can drive that with a VBScript script - not strictly a batch file but VBScript is generally part of Windows.  Of course you can use a batch file to call the vbscript file with the right parameters.

(I've used this technique to schedule things in Outlook - schedule sending an email with a particular subject at a particular time.)

```
'SendMail.vbs

option explicit

' Script for sending mails to myself, with given subject and optionally file contents for body

' Note this only works with particular Schedule service settings, i.e.,
' it has to log on as me and have access to the Desktop

dim fso, f, oMailItem, oOlApp

' Create the mail
Set oOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oMailItem = oOlApp.CreateItem(0) '0 = olMailItem
oMailItem.Subject = WScript.Arguments(0)
oMailItem.Recipients.Add ("receiver.name@somemailserver.com")
if WScript.Arguments.Count > 1 then
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set f = fso.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(1), 1 )
    oMailItem.Body = f.ReadAll
    f.Close
end if   
oMailItem.Send

set f = nothing
set oMailItem = nothing
set oOlApp = nothing
```

Call it with a command like

```
sendmail.vbs My_Subject_Line contents_file.txt
```